# CefSharp GetSourceAsync() as byte array

Tags: c#, cloudflare, cefsharp

I have searched for hours on GitHub, StackOverflow and Google without success, so I think I'm stuck.

I get the source of a page located behind CloudFlare, using CefSharp, with this method :

```
public static string GetCefSource(string url)
{
    Browser.Load(url); //An instance of ChromiumWebBrowser
    Thread.Sleep(15000); //Debatable (it would be better to wait for the real content instead of waiting for "some random time until CloudFlare does its thing")
    string source = Browser.GetSourceAsync().ConfigureAwait(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); //Don't ask me the purpose of ConfigureAwait, NetAnalyzers asks for it (I'll look into it)
    return source;
}
```

It works 100% of the time (for now), but what if I use this method to get an image, in order to write it to the disk ?

With the method above, I get something like

```
"�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\u0001�\0\0\0�\b\u0006..."
```

which is **perfectly normal**. As you can see, it's the PNG image I'm waiting for, as a string, Unicode and so on, but not in the format I need.

I would like to manipulate the image before writing it to the disk, so I need the source as a byte array, in order to use it with

```
using MagickImage image = new(data)
```

So the question is :

How can I get a remote file as a byte array, like I do using HttpClient with

```
HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToArray()
```

but with CefSharp, because of CloudFlare ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can download the url see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/bec06b2495caa82376799131ae778eb553600936#diff-b5d302e3b07bf84e99ffa745fe37affd00a70cae3e5dd66c51911e30540c06c1R329 you'll need version 91 or higher

Comment: @amaitland Incredible, it works like a charm. I slightly modified my method. Can you publish an answer so I can upvote and accept it ? Otherwise I'll publish mine and credit you. It's ugly but my method is now public static object GetCefSource(string url, bool asByteArray = false) { Browser.Load(url); Thread.Sleep(15000); object result = Browser.GetSourceAsync().ConfigureAwait(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();  if (asByteArray) { IFrame mainFrame = Browser.GetMainFrame(); result = mainFrame.DownloadUrlAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }  return result; }

Comment: Shouldn't cloudflare be transparent to any requests unless there are problems? Why can't you use a normal http get request?

Comment: By all means post your own answer.

Comment: @FalcoGer When a site is protected by CloudFlare, you get the CloudFlare page, have to wait for some Javascript to execute, and get the real page. If you use a normal HTTP request, you get this CloudFlare page, not the page behind, because no Javascript is executed. You have to use a real browser like CefSharp to execute this Javascript and wait a bit. Also, if you use CefSharp, but without waiting, you still get the CloudFlare page and not the page behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [amaitland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4583726/amaitland) for [his fast answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68733281/cefsharp-getsourceasync-as-byte-array?noredirect=1#comment121471396_68733281) about [DownloadUrlAsync()](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/bec06b2495caa82376799131ae778eb553600936#diff-b5d302e3b07bf84e99ffa745fe37affd00a70cae3e5dd66c51911e30540c06c1R329).

I can now get any resource located behind CloudFlare, as a string or a byte[], with this :

```
public static object GetCefSource(string url, bool asByteArray = false)
{
    Browser.Load(url); //An instance of ChromiumWebBrowser
    Thread.Sleep(15000); //Wait for CloudFlare's Javascript to execute
    object result = Browser.GetSourceAsync().ConfigureAwait(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    if (asByteArray)
    {
        IFrame mainFrame = Browser.GetMainFrame();
        result = mainFrame.DownloadUrlAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I would probably rewrite it with an alternative to Thread.Sleep() and without the result boxed in an object.

Thanks !